# Запуск программы от другого пользователя и имени машины

Tags: windows

Имеется приложение для Windows которого определяет количество запущенных установок по имени компьютера и пользователя.

Вопрос: как можно запустить программу от другого пользователя это понятно ( runas ) - а как можно запустить программу что бы она увидела иное имя компьютера?

Comment: Так решение задачи зависит от того, как оно (приложение) определяет другой имя компьютера: может считывает с реестра, может через API-функцию GetComputerName и т.д.

Comment: Кстати, вот ссылка на решенный вопрос как изменить имя компа:
 [getComputerNameW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212725/detour-getcomputernamew)